# React JS — how do I add child components and set calculated transformations?

Tags: reactjs

In a standard React JS app, how does one create objects from within, say, a `componentDidMount` method? These objects can be sub-components of the component I'm in, and I want to append them into my existing component which already is rendering a div with id `core-categories` (see below)[image: example code here]

You'll notice my end goal is to be able to programmatically load the array (please consider that beyond the scope of this SO question--for now I am just hard-coding it), having it be of variable length, and then plot the X and Y for each item around a circle using the math you see above.

To do this, I am trying to use CSS transformations (beyond scope of this)

```
class XYZClass extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      transformed: false
    }
    this.nodes = [];
  }

  createNodes (nodes_array, radius) {
    var numNodes = nodes_array.length;

    var nodes = [],
      width = (radius * 2) + 50,
      height = (radius * 2) + 50,
      angle,
      x,
      y,
      i;
    for (i=0; i<numNodes; i++) {
      angle = (i / (numNodes/2)) * Math.PI; // Calculate the angle at which the element will be placed.
      x = (radius * Math.cos(angle)) + (width/2); // Calculate the x position of the element.
      y = (radius * Math.sin(angle)) + (width/2); // Calculate the y position of the element.
      this.nodes.push({'id': i, 'name': nodes_array[i], 'x': x, 'y': y});
    }
    return this.nodes;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({transformed: 'true'});
    }, 0);

    this.createNodes(['Apple','Bananna','Cherry','Date','Elderberry'], 250);

    // create new node component for each of these 5 nodes
    // append into the #core-categories div below programatically based on
    // x and y values calcualted above
    // ???????????????????????????????????????????????????
  }

  render() {
    const { transformed } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div id={'core-categories'} width={'500px'} height={'500px'}>


        </div>


      </div>

    )
  }
}
export default XYZClass;
```

Comment: What are you doing with these "nodes"? Do you have a Node component that accepts these particular props?

Comment: Yes, I intend to. In my first version (where I am at), all 5 can be instantiated from the the same React component class. But then in my refactor, I'd like to separate it so that I can attach five distinct components … like `AppleNode`, `BanannaNode`, `CherryNode`,... that each will have distinct UX/UI and interaction characteristics. So my immediate goal is simply to plot all 5 on a circle, as seen by the trig above.

Comment: You should consider using one `Node` component and passing props that modify the UX/UI and define the "interaction characteristics".

Answer (score 2):

Child components are created during `render()`. In `componentDidMount()`, you should call `setState()` to save the data for these components. Then in `render()` you can create the components from the data by, for instance, calling `map()` on an array. For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({transformed: 'true'});
    }, 0);

    let nodes = this.createNodes(['Apple','Bananna','Cherry','Date','Elderberry'], 250);
    this.setState({nodes});
  }

render() {
    const { transformed, nodes } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div id={'core-categories'} width={'500px'} height={'500px'}>
            {nodes.map((nodeProps) => <Node {...nodeProps}>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Note: I don't think you need the `setTimeout()`. You can call `this.setState()` directly. I left it anyway because it isn't critical to the question.

Comment: this answer is close. note that `{nodes.map((nodeProps) => <Node {...nodeProps}>)}`, my version of React will expect the <Node> component (poorly named) to be self-closing `{nodes.map((nodeProps) => <Node {...nodeProps} />)}`

Comment: … how I set the X and Y coordinates of the newly created component object? Your code works, but they just come out as a list. I want to plot them around the circle, which should be available via the `x` and `y` coordinates that were calculated in the method above

Comment: @JasonFB You do that in your `Node` class, or possibly with some CSS. But we need more details in order to help. What are you plotting exactly? What should the result look like? This is a completely new question and involves the code in your `Node` component that you don't show here. I suggest that you post a new question including these details. For more suggestions on how to ask a good question that attracts the answers you need, see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: well, not exactly.  it simply plots them around a circle, which is calculated in the `createNodes` method above. What's tricky is that I want it programatic, so I can add `N` number of points (nodes) around the circle, and have them plotted automatically. That's essentially the goal.

Comment: @JasonFB Please answer all of my questions in my previous comment. In particular, what do you want the end result to look like? Use MS Paint or something similar to draw a mock.

Comment: I was able to get this working by just setting props on the constructor, like so ```<InfoBox key={2} blurb={{name: "Quis maximus nisl est et diam"}} top_pos={"20"} left_pos={"75"} />```. I think was making it harder than it should have been

Comment: the `InfoBox` constructor sets the props to the state (and can default them there too), and then the `render()` method pulls them out of the state  ```const top_pos = this.props.top_pos || 100;    const left_pos = this.props.left_pos || 400
``` and then renders them like so  ```<StyledInfoBox onClick={this.selectBox}  style={{top: top_pos + "%", left: left_pos + "%"}}>
```

Comment: @JasonFB Glad to see you figured something out. Note that what you describe doesn't use the constructor or state at all. When you do `<InfoBox ...>` you are passing values as props. Your solution is definitely better than what I mentioned in my answer here.